# Find the sum of the series $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(\frac{n+1}{2^n}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\left(\frac{n+1}{2^n}\right)$$

I know that I can separate it into: $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\left(\frac{n}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2^n}\right)$

And I am able to prove that the second part gives the sum 2, but the first one is a bit problematic, any tips?